# How to execute some code after changing tabs in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I created an gui interface with `tkinter` which contains notebook tabs, the first tabs contains input file to upload csv file, in the second tab I want to read the uploaded file and show results, the problem is the content of the second tab was executed on loading the gui interface, how can I can execute the content of second tab only when the file was uploaded?

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
import os
import importlib
import csv
import os.path


class Notebook:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title('Traitement fichier csv')
        self.build_Menu()
        self.build_NoteBook()
        self.build_page_1()
        self.build_page_2()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def build_Menu(self):
        # MENU WIDGET CONFIGURATION
        self.menu = Menu(self.root)
        self.root.configure(menu=self.menu)
        self.filemenu = [None] * 3
        for f in range(1,3):
            self.filemenu[f] = Menu(self.menu,tearoff=False)
        #FILE MENU
        self.menu.add_cascade(label='File', menu=self.filemenu[1])
        for i in ['New','Open','Exit']:
            if i == 'New':
                self.filemenu[1].add_command(label=i,command=self.Add_New_Tab)
            elif i == 'open':
                self.filemenu[1].add_command(label=i,command=self.filedialog)
            elif i == 'Exit':
                self.filemenu[1].add_command(label=i,command=quit)
            else:
                self.filemenu[1].add_command(label=i)

    # ADD NEW TAG CODE
    def Add_New_Tab(self):
            for k in range(2,3):
                self.notebook.add(self.tab[k],text=f'Page {k}')

    def build_NoteBook(self):
        # NOTEBOOK WIDGET CONFIGURATION
        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(self.root,height=400,width=800)

        self.tab = [None] * 10
        global t
        for t in range(1,10):
            self.tab[t] = ttk.Frame(self.notebook)

        self.notebook.add(self.tab[1],text='Importation des donnees',underline=0)
        self.notebook.add(self.tab[2], text='Affichage des donnees apres traitement ')
        # self.notebook.add(self.tab[3], text='Page 3')
        # self.notebook.add(self.tab[4], text='Page 4')
        self.notebook.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES, padx=5, pady=5)

        #PAGE ONE CONTENTS
    def build_page_1(self):
        ttk.Button(self.tab[1], text='Ouvrir un fichier csv', command=self.filedialog).pack(side=LEFT,anchor=CENTER,padx=90,pady=5,fill=X,expand=1)
        #ttk.Button(self.tab[1], text='close', command=quit).pack(side=LEFT, padx=90, fill=X, anchor=CENTER,expand=1)

    def filedialog(self):
        self.filename= filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",title = "Select a file",filetypes = (("csv files","*.csv"),("all files","*.*")))
        print(self.filename)
        #os.system('python deleteNull.py')
        #global filename
        #filename=self.filename
        importlib.import_module("deleteNull")

    def build_page_2(self):
        data = []
        path="C:/Users/ThinkPad/Desktop/Python/fout.csv"
        if(os.path.exists(path)):
            input_file = 'fout.csv'
            with open(input_file, "r") as source:
                reader = csv.reader(source)
                next(reader, None)  # skip the headers
                for row in reader:
                    data.append( [row[0], row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4]])

            tree = ttk.Treeview(self.tab[2], columns = (1,2,3,4,5), height = 50, show = "headings")
            tree.pack(side = 'left')
            tree.heading(1, text="Matricule")
            tree.heading(2, text="Date Inscription")
            tree.heading(3, text="Cycle")
            tree.heading(4, text="Specialité")
            tree.heading(5, text="Durée cursus")

            tree.column(1, width = 150)
            tree.column(2, width = 150)
            tree.column(3, width = 150)
            tree.column(4, width = 150)
            tree.column(5, width = 180)

            scroll = ttk.Scrollbar(self.tab[2], orient="vertical", command=tree.yview)
            scroll.pack(side = 'right', fill = 'y')

            tree.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)

        for val in data:
            tree.insert('', 'end', values = (val[0], val[1], val[2],val[3],val[4]) )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Notebook()
```

Comment: Can't just move `build_page_2` inside your `filedialog` function?

Comment: @HenryYik you are genius i'ts working